# R Package development: how to update the 'doc' folder with new vignettes

Tags: r, package, devtools

I noticed that, in R, when I use `install.packages` to download my own library, it will create a `doc` folder in `\R\3.3\win-library\PACKAGENAME\` in which vignette HTML files will be stored.

However, if I use RStudio to build my package from source, this `doc` folder is not created. If it is already there, it is not updated (i.e.: it just keeps older versions of the vignettes and will not add new ones).

Seems like an odd behaviour. Is there any way to have RStudio update the contents of the `doc` folder?

Thank you!

Andrew